# Running test cases in Eclipse using JUnit

Tags: java, oracle, junit, junit4

I'm trying to run a test using JUnit in Eclipse but the test case is not running and the holly console not showing anything. The only line appears in console is :

```
<terminated>AccountManagmentModuleTest[JUnit] D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\javaw.exe(Nov 23, 2012 12:08:49 PM)
```

All I want to do is run the test case. Some lines are executing, like starting to connect to db, but no connection object created using DriverManager, also don't throw any exception.

```
enter code here

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@local ip:1521:orcl", "dipak1","dipak1"); //got to finally from here, not even catching anything!!!
            cstmt = conn.prepareCall(query);  
            cstmt.execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (null != conn) {

                if (null != cstmt) {
                    cstmt.close();

                }
                conn.close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: can you show us the test and where it stops?

Comment: Also, can you show us how you run the tests? Also, consider trying with a clean workspace

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski : conn is turened to null , and no exception catch there.
after that get connection it gose to finally block and stops eventually. :(

Comment: That URL looks strange, have you tried `jdbc:oracle:oci8:@local:1521:orlc` instead? Also I would try to debug the test, set a breakpoint at getConnection() line, start the test in debug mode and step through (or into getConnection()).

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski actually my usrl was jdbc:oracle:oci8:@192.168.2.17:1521:orlc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your test is executing but not producing the outputs you expect. Ensure you have the JUnit view open:

***Window > Show View > Other... > Java > JUnit***

This view will show you visually how many tests have run and how many have passed. If the tests are failing, you can right-click on the failed tests and debug them. You can also see the exceptions that have occurred.

The Console window won't show you any output from your JUnit tests unless you've including output statements in your test (either through a logging framework or simple `println` statements). Only the JUnit view will show you whether your tests passed.

Comment: JUnit view is open, its some problem with initial config ithik. I told you about console window because there no single line of log is appearing on it, that mean the execution isn't started. 
The thing is that today i changed whole my files and settings to new pc, it was working good in old pc, but in new got some problem.

you can tel me some configuration that should be done before i start to work on junit.
My project is a maven, using a Oracle db(Remote), deploying in Embedded glass-fish.

Answer (score 1):

When you doing Unit testing with Junit, you should not use try and catch block use throws Exception.
Instead of if (null != conn) use JUnit assertion testing (assertNotNull or assertEquals or another one).
To run the JUNit test on Eclipse :

1. Window > Show View > Other... > Java > JUnit
2. Right clic on the java file > Run as > JUnit test.
3. On the panel JUnit you can see the unit testing result is succes or failed.

   import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

   import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

   import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

   import org.junit.Test;

   ```
   @Test
   public void testDbConnexion() throws Exception
   {
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@local ip:1521:orcl", "dipak1","dipak1"); //got to finally from here, not even catching anything!!!
         cstmt = conn.prepareCall(query);  
         cstmt.execute();
         assertNotNull(conn);
         assertNotNull(cstmt);
         connn.close();
   }
   ```